# ValueError: shapes

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run this code on Spider(Python 3.8)  but I run in this error:" ValueError: shapes (4,) and (3,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)"

```
import numpy as np 

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 2.5]
weights = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
       [0.5, -0.81, 1.7, -0.91],
       [-0.67, 3, 0.6, -0.98]]

biases = [2, 3, 0.5]

output = np.dot(inputs, weights) + biases
print(output)
```

could you help me?

Comment: `np.dot(weights, inputs) + biases`

Comment: (re)read the `np.dot` docs with a focus on how the dimensions interact.

Answer (score 0):

If A be any  m * n matrix and both AB and BA are defined prove that B should be  m * n matrix